# How do I specify to rails which version of ruby I would like to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

Before judging this question please listen to these details: 
           I have tried twenty million things to "update" ruby so that it is compatible with ruby on rails. The problem is that I cannot make changes to anything in the bin of my macbook. The terminal simply does not allow it. So, I installed a new version of ruby via the command line that is 2.5.1. How do I direct rails via the terminal to use this version instead of the version in my bin?

Comment: I would recommend using a version manager, either https://rvm.io/rvm/install  or https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv  then in your Gemfile `ruby '2.5.1'

Comment: You can specify a Ruby version in your gemfile but it is for production: Heroku hosts many versions of ruby. You can tell Heroku to use a specific version. Locally, you should use Ruby Version Manager or such, so that you can switch between the different Ruby versions installed on your computer. Then tour current Ruby version has to match the one in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

From the official Rails Guides website.

- Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.4.1 or newer.
- Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or
  newer.
- Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0 and requires 1.9.3 or newer.
- Rails 3.2.x is the last branch to support Ruby 1.8.7.
- Rails 3 and above require Ruby 1.8.7 or higher.

While Rails 6 is still unreleased, this is a preliminary guess, given from the current master-branch of the official repository, at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.md

From edge-guides:

- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions